# Mudar elemento HTML de posição com each (ou outra sugestão) no carregamento da página

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

Eu preciso acessar a `div` com `id list` e mudar a posição dos `span`. Está assim:

```
<div id="list">
<div class='item'>
    <span class="AB">conteudo 1</span>
    <span class="AA">conteudo 2</span>
</div>
<div class='item'>
    <span class="AB">conteudo 3</span>
    <span class="AA">conteudo 4</span>
</div>
```

Preciso que fique assim:

```
<div id="list">
<div class='item'>
    <span class="AA">conteudo 2</span>
    <span class="AB">conteudo 1</span>
</div>
<div class='item'>
    <span class="AA">conteudo 4</span>
    <span class="AB">conteudo 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Te interesse uma resposta para resolver isso apenas com CSS ou vc quer que seja com js ou jQuery mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só mais uma maneira de fazer para deixar registrado:

```js
$(function() {
  var cont_AA = $('.AA');
  
  $('.item').each(function(i) {
    $('.item:eq('+i+')').append(cont_AA[i]);
    $('.AB:eq('+i+')').insertAfter(cont_AA[i]);
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <div class='item'>
    <span class="AB">conteudo 1</span>
    <span class="AA">conteudo 2</span>
  </div> <br>
  <div class='item'>
    <span class="AB">conteudo 3</span>
    <span class="AA">conteudo 4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agradeço a todos, mas acabei adaptando essa forma para minha necessidade. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Veja se o exemplo abaixo pode te ajudar.

```js
$("button").on('click',mudarPosicao);

function mudarPosicao(){
    // pega cada elemento DIV dentro do id='list'
   $("#list > DIV").each(function(i,el){
     var pai = $(el), // elemento DIV
         filhos = pai.children(), // spans
         primeiroFilho = filhos.eq(0); // primeiro span
     pai.append( primeiroFilho ) // isso faz com que ele va para o final, ou seja o primerio agora é o segundo
   })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
<div class='item'>
    <span class="AB">conteudo 1</span>
    <span class="AA">conteudo 2</span>
</div>
<div class='item'>
    <span class="AB">conteudo 3</span>
    <span class="AA">conteudo 4</span>
</div>
</div>
<button>
Mudar posição
</button>
```

[Tree Traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/), [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/#eq-index)

Answer (score 0):

Para reorganizar de forma decrescente de acordo com o valor numérico do texto, você pode usar além do `.each()`, o `.sort()`. Desta forma, não importa a quantidade de spans nas divs:

```js
$(function(){
   
   $("#list .item").each(function(){
      
      var $this = $(this); // div pai
   
      $("span", this).sort(function(a, b){ // seleciona os spans
         var v1 = $(a).text().match(/\d+/)[0]; // pega o valor numérico
         var v2 = $(b).text().match(/\d+/)[0]; // pega o valor numérico
         return -1; // ordem decrescente
      }).appendTo($this);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
   <div class='item'>
       <span class="AB">conteudo 1</span>
       <span class="AB">conteudo 2</span>
   </div>
   <div class='item'>
       <span class="AB">conteudo 3</span>
       <span class="AA">conteudo 4</span>
   </div>
</div>
```